# Check sum of inputs before submit

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help: I have the following form:

```
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="?action=agc">
<input type="hidden" name="start_date" value="<?= $_POST['start_date'] ?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="end_date" value="<?= $_POST['end_date'] ?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="c_name" value="<?= $_POST['c_name'] ?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="cluster" value='<?= $abn_cluster[0] ?>' />
<input type="hidden" name="abn" value="abn" />

<a href="javascript:addOption();">Add percent</a> <br /><br />
ABN percent<br />
<input type="text" name="poll[option][0][percent]" class="toAdd">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="poll[option][0][name]" value="<?= $_POST['c_name'] ?>_0_">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="optionBox" value="True" name="poll[option][0][control_sample]" /><br />

<script> 
var optionNumber = 1;  
function addOption() { 
    var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm"); 
    var newOption = document.createElement("input"); 
    var newOption2 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var newOption3 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("  ");
    var newContent2 = document.createTextNode("  ");

    newOption.name = "poll[option]["+optionNumber+"][percent]";
    newOption.type = "text";
    theForm.appendChild(newOption);
    theForm.appendChild(newContent);
    newOption2.name = "poll[option]["+optionNumber+"][name]";
    newOption2.type = "text";
    newOption2.value = "<?= $_POST['c_name'] ?>_"+optionNumber+"_"
    theForm.appendChild(newOption2);
    theForm.appendChild(newContent2);

    newOption3.name = "poll[option]["+optionNumber+"][control_sample]";
    newOption3.type = "checkbox";
    newOption3.className = "optionBox";
    newOption3.value = "True"
    theForm.appendChild(newOption3);

    theForm.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); 
    optionNumber++;
}
</script>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer" id="appendform">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
    </form>
```

Now because some of the inputs are generated on request, I have no idea how to check the sum of the(.toAdd). And I basically need to make sure that it's equal to 100 before submitting. What would be a solution to my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Loop through the form on the `onsubmit` event? If there's something wrong, let the user know and stop the process.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="iap_crm_campaign.php?action=abngamecampaign" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Then

```
function validate(){
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < optionNumber; i++){
        sum += parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('poll[option][' + i + '][percent]')[0].value);
    }

    if( sum == NaN || sum != 100){
        alert('Sum of percentage must be 100');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WJrhG/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = 0;
var toAdds = document.getElementsByClassName("toAdd");
for (var i = 0; i < toAdds.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(toAdds[i].value, 0);
}
if (total == 100) {
  // OK
} else {
  // not OK
}
```

Also, your code for adding new options needs to set the class:

```
newOption.className = "toAdd";
```

Comment: can you please explain      " newOption.className = "toAdd"; "

Comment: @AbdulWaheed It sets the class of the element, like `<option class="toAdd">` in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery

```
$(".toAdd").length
```

or  in simple js

```
var myInputs= document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var noOfInputs =myInputs.length;
```

well this will give you the count of i/p elements through loop, for summing the values...

```
var sum;
$(".toAdd").each(function() {
    sum=sum+$(this).val();
});
```

Comment: And that doesn't add up the values even if he were.

Comment: I do have jquery. Major issue - no idea how anything front end works. Including javascript. Or anything that has user interface for that matter.

Comment: @alxkls There are plenty of good jQuery books and tutorials. Maybe you should learn how to use your tools, rather than relying on Internet randoms to do your programming for you.

Comment: @rps Your code still doesn't check that the total of all the percentages is 100. Where did you get the idea that he cares about the number of inputs?

Comment: @Barmar, I thought he wanted to get the no. of randomly generated inputs so that he can add their values and check if it is 100, must have misinterpreted